# java Date(long) doesn't make sense.. a long isn't big enough to store the current date in milliseconds

Tags: java, datetime, date

The java Date class expects a long:

But the current Date/time to millisecond precision is too large to be held in a long.

Hello.java:14: integer number too large: 1335250803004
    long l  = 1335250803004;

So how on earth does this work?

Comment: It works the same on other planets too... but it will be good to write a unit test for that. :) (sorry could not resist)

Comment: try to add letter "L" after your number: `long l = 1335250803004L;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A milliseconds value represents the number of milliseconds that have passed since **January 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT**  [[..]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28long%29)

So [it is able to hold Dates upto](http://ideone.com/7u0R5)

```
08-17-292278994
```

Answer (score 2):

Huh?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println(new Date().getTime());
    System.out.println(new Date().getTime() < Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

Prints:

```
9223372036854775807
1337770864719
true
```